# Android ICS ROMs for MID Tablet

Tags: wi-fi, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, device-firmware

I have a MID (Chinese) tablet and I found 2 Android 4.0 firmwares, but with the first one wireless doesn't work and with the second camera doesn't work, the other components and functions of my tablet work perfectly with both firmwares.

Is there a way to extract the "wireless driver" from the second firmware and use it on the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on my experience with Chinese-made MID, we can extract it ONLY if we have the access to it's kernel (which usually the manufacturer doesn't release it). Maybe you can start looking for the solution at [tabletrepublic.com](http://tabletrepublic.com) forum.

Find the specific device model and chipset used, and I am sure there will be a lot devs out there willing to help.